# List of practical quantum computing algorithms that have speed-up higher than quadratic speed-up?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-advantage

From this [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.04149) (provided by @KAJ226's comment in this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15386/are-applications-with-only-polynomial-speedup-worth-chasing-after-since-error)), it appears as though current error correction methods are not enough to get practical speedup out of algorithms that have quadratic speedups (before taking error correction into account).

In another post, I showed a chart of speedups of different machine learning algorithms. All of these algorithms do not have quartic or higher speedups (and therefore will not be practical with error correction).

Is there a list of practical algorithms that have quartic or higher speedup? I found one such list called the [quantum zoo](https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org/), but it only provides if a given algorithm is "polynomial" or "superpolynomial." Also it doesn't seem very up-to-date and the impact or practicality of these algorithms is not mentioned (a lot of these seem useless or are very vague).

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet as of now is to derive such a table from the [Quantum Algorithm Zoo](https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org/), which, as you mention although partly dated, would serve as a good starting point but would require reading between the lines.  For example, the Zoo mentions a speedup in [solving exponential congruences](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1109) of $\tilde{O}(q^{3/8})$ quantum, but a $\tilde{O}(q^{9/8})$ classical algorithm.

The Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm (QAOA) initially appears promising to get the speedups on NISQ-error devices, but it happens that *lower bounds* on classical algorithms may also be dated and can be significantly improved once a quantum algorithm comes along. This is what has happened with QAOA for Max-E3LIN.  See the nice Quanta article [here](https://www.quantamagazine.org/quantum-computers-struggle-against-classical-algorithms-20180201/).

Comment: Just to be clear the "exponential congruence" example you give is not faster than quadratic right?

Comment: Looking at it closer, yeah it's not faster than quadratic.  Sorry for implying it was.