# Is quantum machine learning faster than classical machine learning (at the moment)?

Tags: machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

We all know that quantum computing is rapidly developing and somehow being used in the AI field. However, it seems like there's no specific comparison between quantum machine learning (could be deep learning) and classical machine learning.

D-wave has a quantum computer (annealer) and own library as well as pennylane (Xanadu) and IBM, even Google. My question is "are these devices really run hybrid or quantum machine learning?".

Comment: related: [*What is the advantage of quantum machine learning over traditional machine learning?*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13531/55), [*What are the benefits of using quantum machine learning?*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13368/55), [*Are there quantum algorithms demonstrating speedup computing classical neural networks (in 2021)?*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15385/55). See also https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09664 for a recent review on the subject

Answer (score 1):

this is Catalina from Xanadu. You will often see the comparison between classical and quantum machine learning in papers.

The way quantum machine learning works is that you have a quantum computer which runs the quantum part of your algorithm and a classical computer which runs the classical part of your algorithm. Depending on your algorithm you will use both quantum and classical resources in different ways.

If you want to learn more I suggest you check out the [PennyLane Demos page](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos_qml.html), where you will see different quantum machine learning algorithms being used on quantum computers and simulators.

I hope this helped answer your question!

Comment: Welcome to the site! As far as I can tell, this doesn't quite address the titular question though, which asks about speed comparisons between QML and ML algorithms (in fairness, that question probably has no good easy answer at the moment, but still)